# Are 4-dimensional mapping tori always spin?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, 4-manifolds

We know that all compact orientable manifolds of dimension 3 are spin.
In 4 dimensions, $CP^2$ is not spin. I would like to ask if
all 4-dimensional compact orientable mapping tori are spin?

See also a related question [Spin structure on mapping torus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72766/spin-structure-on-mapping-torus)

Comment: No, for example $\mathbb RP^2 \times S^1 \times S^1$ is not orientable, so it is not spin.  Do you mean to ask a different question?  The question you cite seems to answer your question here.

Comment: I am sorry, I mean orientable ones. I update the question. Thanks!

Comment: The question I cited is related, but it did not directly answer  if all 4-dimensional compact orientable mapping tori are spin.

Comment: I think the answer is the mapping torus admits a spin structure if and only if the monodromy of the 3-manifold fixes a spin structure.  You should be able to construct a diffeomorphism of $(S^1)^3$ that does not fix any spin structures.

Comment: @RyanBudney : won't a (orientation-preserving?) diffeomorphism of the 3-torus always fix the trivial spin structure, due to the fact that this the only one which has a non-trivial kernel for its associated Dirac operator?

Comment: @RyanBudney: I think the issue is that for any orientation-preserving diffeomorphism $f$ of 3-dim spin $M$, can we always find a spin structure on $M$ that is not changed by $f$.

Comment: @Xiao-GangWen : I think I found an example that shows this is not the case. Consider the projective 3-space $\mathbb{P}^3:=S^3/(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$. It has 2 different spin structures, which are mapped to each other by a diffeomorphism as follows: embed $S^3$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$ in the standard way, and let $\phi$ be the diffeomorphism given by $x_1\mapsto x_3$, $x_2\mapsto x_4$ and vice-versa. This induces a map on $\mathbb{P}^3$ that interchanges the two spin structures. However, this does not suffice to show that there is no spin structure on the resulting mapping torus, I think.

Comment: @JanJitseVenselaar : If the mapping torus that you constructed has a non-zero Stiefel-Whitney number for $w_2 w_2$, then it cannot be spin. So can you show that the Stiefel-Whitney number for $w_2 w_2$ is 1. Or more generally, can you show $w_2$ is non-zero for your mapping torus?

Comment: @JanJitseVenselaar: The Dirac operator depends on a metric, so the property of invertibility isn't a diffeomorphism invariant. A rephrase of this argument uses the Rohlin invariant of a spin 3-manifold: make it bound a spin 4-manifold and consider the signature modulo 16. $T^3$ has 8 spin structures; 7 of them have Rohlin invariant 0 since they extend over $T^2\times D^2$ glued on in various ways.  The last one, which you're calling the trivial spin structure, has Rohlin invariant 8. So it's preserved by any orientation-preserving diffeomorphism.

Comment: @JanJitseVenselaar: While we're at it, the Rohlin invariants for the two spin structures on $RP^3$ are $\pm 1$, so they can't be interchanged by an orientation-preserving diffeomorphism. (See Gompf-Stipsicz, exercise 5.7.17(a).) The diffeomorphism you construct is isotopic to the identity, so certainly preserves each spin structure.

Comment: @DannyRuberman: You're totally right on both counts. I was (incorrectly) thinking about just isometries in the first case. As for the $RP^3$ case: I think I missed a - sign somewhere in my diffeomorphism, so it actually becomes an orientation reversing diffeomorphism, which is compatible I guess with the Rohlin-invariant, but doesn't help in answering the question. I see now that Ryan answered the question with a nice explicit counterexample.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is no.  As was described in the thread: [Spin structure on mapping torus](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72766/spin-structure-on-mapping-torus)

a mapping torus has a spin structure if and only if the monodromy of the bundle (over $S^1$) fixes a spin structure.  The mapping torus I'm going to describe is a bundle over $S^1$ with fibre $S^1 \times S^2$.

The mapping class group of $S^1 \times S^2$ is of order $8$.  If you pass to the subgroup that preserves the fundamental classes of the factors, you get a subgroup of order $2$, the generator can be thought of as the diffeomorphism that twists the $S^2$ factor by $2 \pi$ as one walks around the circle factor.

This automorphism does not preserve any spin structure on $S^1 \times S^2$, it acts as an involution on the spin structures, with no fixed spin structures.

Comment: Do you have the ref for *The mapping class group of $S^1\times S^2$ is of order 8*.

Comment: @Xiao-GangWen See Theorem 5.1 of Gluck's 1962 paper "The embedding of two-spheres in the four-sphere" http://www.jstor.org/stable/1993581

Comment: @Xiao-GangWen: j.c.'s reference is probably as good as any.  I'm not sure when it was originally proved.  But the basic argument is fairly simple.  The action of the mapping class group on $H_i(S^1 \times S^2)$ gives an epi-morphism to $\mathbb Z_2^2$. A little cut-and-paste topology shows you that diffeomorphisms in the kernel must preserve fibres of the bundle $S^1 \times S^2 \to S^1$ (projection onto the first factor), moreover, they must preserve orientation of $S^2$.  So by Smale's theorem on $Diff(S^2)$, such an element is in $\pi_1 Diff^+(S^2) = \pi_1 SO_2 = \mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: That last $SO_2$ should have been $SO_3$.  There is a homotopy-equivalence $O_3 \simeq Diff(S^2)$ and $SO_3 \simeq Diff^+(S^2)$.